# Why did Twin Saga appear slightly off screen?

Tags: pc, twin-saga

I installed Twin Saga from their website yesterday. It downloaded and installed fine. I ran it and changed the graphics settings to windowed mode. this makes the game appear in a borderless window, which is great.

The game loaded in the top left of my screen, leaving a gap. I noticed that the top and left of the game window were somehow rendering outside of my monitor, so to speak. While trying to create a character, I noticed that the game was registering the mouse above and to the right of my true mouse position. This lead me to beleive that the entire game was rendering in the wrong place, but everything else was fine.

This meant that I couldn't click buttons in the bottom right of the window, because my mouse would be outside the window and would change focus to my desktop.

I started up the game in fullscreen mode and had the same issue.

Is there a way to prevent this? I may resort to installing steam on my new laptop and re-downloading the game through steam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it.

After clicking "play" in the launcher, I had a popup box saying that my graphics drivers weren't up to date, which could lead to some issues during gameplay. I updated my drivers and re-launched the game and had no issues.